# Return custom process command in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, bash

I want to launch the following script in bash

```
php mysript.php
```

and the "ps -A | grep php" command returns something if the script is running.

Is there any way to customize this "php" command with another name? I want to write

```
myphp myscript.php
```

and "ps -A | grep php" should return nothing, but "ps -A | grep myphp" should return something if the script is running.

I tried setting an alias for php command but still "ps" command returns "php" and not "myphp"

I also tried modifying the $PATH variable with a symbolic link from myphp to php in /usr/bin, but still returns "php"

Thanks

Comment: You can write a unix service so you can do something like `systemctl start <my script>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make a symlink to php binary:

`ln -s /usr/bin/php /usr/bin/myphp`

Now `ps -A | grep myphp` shows the running process.

Comment: I swear I tried that method and it didn't work. With your answer I tried again and now it worked. Thanks